# How to partition a reactive observable by a key and merge the partitions into groups combine last element of each partition of the group

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an hot observable of a sequence of items that are have a key that identifies a specific sub-stream. I'm interested to map those M streams into N with N < M (group them into N buckets). For each bucket, each time an element arrives, I want to apply a function to the latest element of each underlining sequence of that group. I've prior knowledge of both N and M groups.

In the following sample, we have a sequence of quote for four fruits. I want to map those streams into two, by the type of fruit (Apple or Pear). For each group I want to collect the last known quote of each fruit.

```cs
class Input {
    public string ProductID {get;set;}
    public string ProductType {get;set;}
    public int    Price {get;set;}
}

class Output {
    public string  ProductType {get;set;}
    public Input[] Underlining {get;set;}
}

var obs = new List<Input> {
    new Input { ProductID = "Stark",    ProductType = "Apple", Price = 21 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Jonagold", ProductType = "Apple", Price = 12 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Williams", ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 33 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Beth",     ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 22 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Stark",    ProductType = "Apple", Price = 43 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Williams", ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 55 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Beth",     ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 66 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Jonagold", ProductType = "Apple", Price = 77 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Jonagold", ProductType = "Apple", Price = 25 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Williams", ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 77 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Beth",     ProductType = "Pear",  Price = 13 },
    new Input { ProductID = "Stark",    ProductType = "Apple", Price = 21 },
}.ToObservable();

IObservable<Output> result = obs.GroupBy ... Select ... Concat ... ; // I'm a bit loss here 


result.Dump();
```

Expected result:

```cs
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = 21 }] }
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = 21 },     { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 12 }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 23 }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 23 },     { ProductID = "Beth",     Price = 22 }] }
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = **43** }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 12 }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = **55** }, { ProductID = "Beth",     Price = 22 }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 55 },     { ProductID = "Beth",     Price = **66** }] }
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = 43 },     { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = **77** }] }
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = 43 },     { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = **25** }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = **77** }, { ProductID = "Beth",     Price = 66 }] }
{ ProductType = "Pear",  Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 77 },     { ProductID = "Beth",     Price = **13** }] }
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark",    Price = **21** }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 25 }] }
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. I appreciate the example code, but you haven't explained fully what the data means. The first paragraph does mention `SourceKey`, but nothing about `GroupKey`, and `Value`. Can you please change these properties to something like `Name`, `Location, & `Age` to try and make it easier to understand? Then please explain how the expect result would come out. Also, compilable code for `obs` and your result would be great.

Comment: Thanks reading and taking time to reply. I've tried to do as you suggested. I've omitted in the expected result the ProductType to improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var outputs =
    obs
        .GroupBy(x => x.ProductType)
        .Select(xs =>
            xs
                .Scan(
                    new Dictionary<string, Input>(),
                    (d, x) => { d[x.ProductID] = x; return d; })
                .Select(x => new Output()
                {
                    ProductType = xs.Key,
                    Underlining = x.Values.ToArray(),
                }))
        .Merge();
```

I used `outputs.Select(x => $"{{ ProductType = \"{x.ProductType}\", Underlining = [{String.Join(", ", x.Underlining.Select(y => $"{{ ProductID = \"{y.ProductID}\", Price = {y.Price} }}"))}] }}")` to get the following output to test it:

```
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 21 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 21 }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 12 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 33 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 33 }, { ProductID = "Beth", Price = 22 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 43 }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 12 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 55 }, { ProductID = "Beth", Price = 22 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 55 }, { ProductID = "Beth", Price = 66 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 43 }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 77 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 43 }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 25 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 77 }, { ProductID = "Beth", Price = 66 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Pear", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Williams", Price = 77 }, { ProductID = "Beth", Price = 13 }] } 
{ ProductType = "Apple", Underlining = [{ ProductID = "Stark", Price = 21 }, { ProductID = "Jonagold", Price = 25 }] }
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about `Scan` and was struggling with this.. but where does the selection of `Max` value happen?

Comment: @supertopi - What "Max"? The requirement was "last known quote of each fruit". Did I miss something?